# Free product with amalgamation vs pushout

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-product

As in title, in terms of group theory (I'm not familiar with category-theoretic terms), question comes from algebraic topology but seems to be of general interest. (Other questions on MSE touch on the topic but I haven't found a direct answer).

What is the difference between the two? Is one special case of the other?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation

Comment: @Javi it means these are the same right? If so feel free to make it an answer

Comment: It is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261767/free-product-with-amalgamation-is-correspondingly-a-pushout). If that answer is not satisfactory to you then I'll try to make my own.

Comment: The answer there says it's the same thing *up to isomorphism*. How is that caveat relevant? Is there some other way to compare these groups?

Comment: In general, groups or objects in any category are compared by the morphisms between them. One cannot expect nothing better than having an isomorphism, which is almost like sayint they're the same. For example, the groups $\{0,1\}$ with sum modulo 2 and $\{-1,1\}$ with the product can be regarded as the same group, though the elements and the product are described differently.

Comment: This is because their group structure (the multiplication table) is the same, you have two elements - say $a$ and $b$ - and the rules $aa=bb=a$, $ab=ba=b$. If you construct another group satisfying the unviersal property of a pushout, it might look different, but it will be indistinguishable from the free product with amalgamation as an object in the category of groups.

Comment: In conclusion, the free product with amalgamation is a particular case of a pushout.

Comment: The free product with amalgamation is a realization of the pushout when both structural morphisms (the two morphisms that are given as part of the “data” of the pushout diagram) are embeddings.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin can you give a concrete example to when this is not the case? I feel like I'm missing some definitional subtlety.
If I understand you correctly this would mean that the "data" homomorphisms have to be injective

Comment: When what is not the case? If you have a pushout $H\to G$, $H\to K$, the pushout is not going to be $G*_HK$ (which may not even make sense) unless you are identifying $H$ with its image in $G$ and in $K$. And if the image in $G$ is not isomorphic to the image in $K$ (say, the map to $G$ is trivial, and the map to $K$ is an embedding), then you certainly won’t get the amalgamated free product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that is precisely the kind of description that I needed. If you could make this an answer, so that this question can be closed, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the category of groups, the free product with amalgamation is the realization of the pushout when both functions are embeddings. More generally, say that $f\colon H\to G$ and $g\colon H\to K$ is a pushout diagram. If $\mathrm{ker}(f)=\mathrm{ker}(g)$, then the pushout is given (up to unique isomorphism) by $G*_{f(H)\sim g(H)}K$.

However, there are pushouts that cannot be realized as the free amalgamated product. For example, if $H$ is nontrivial, $f$ is the trivial map, and $g$ is an embedding, then you can’t get the amalgamated free product, because you cannot amalgamate the trivial image of $H$ in $G$ with the nontrivial image of $H$ in $K$.

Comment: What is your definition of amalgamated product ? (I often saw the *definition* to be a pushout)

Comment: @Max: It can be defined as the pushout of the embeddings of the subgroup; or it can be defined as the free product modulo the normal closure of the subgroup consisting of elements $i_1(h)i_(h)^{-1}$ with $h\in H$.

Comment: @Max: The point is that the amalgamated product is supposed to be generated by a subgroup isomorphic to $G$ and a subgroup isomorphic to $K$, such that the intersection of those two subgroups is exactly $H$ (as identified by the embeddings). Or as having the corresponding universal property. You need a copy of the same subgroup in both groups for it to make sense.